# Bluetooth Module Appears Not to Be working

Tags: bluetooth, buildroot

I've built a Buildroot linux image for my PhidgetSBC and included bluetooth support unfortunately it appears my bluetooth USB dongle isn't working. Although I have not tested it with code it's internal LED does not illuminate when I plug it in.

When I issue lsmod I see this:

```
Module                  Size  Used by    Not tainted
usb_storage            33699  - 
btusb                   8560  - 
bluetooth              50130  -
```

It appears bluetooth is in the kernel but how could I test my usb dongle?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not Buildroot related, but rather hardware and kernel configuration rleated. Unfortunately, you're giving way too few details: which Bluetooth USB dongle you're talking about, what kernel version using, what is your kernel configuration, etc.

First of all, check if your USB device appears when running `lsusb`.